# Read, arrange and transform it to Excel in ruby

Tags: ruby

**input file: input.txt**

```
Record: C:/my_files/00_Roll_Tom-values.txt

#RakeBoss-Random as on 12/19/2016
[groups]
met = chk\rel_io_chk, chk\dev_op_io,
div = chk\kzhr2x, chk\zz52t0, chk\czzjrt
rakeonly = chk\rzgnsd, chk\cztw5h

[/]
@met = rw
@div = rw
@rakeonly = r
*******************************************************************************************
Record: C:/my_files/Rander-values.txt

#RakeBoss-Jan 21st QA
[groups]
met = chk\rel_io_chk, chk\dev_op_io
div = chk\541kmj, chk\zz52t0
app_only = chk\zz9ycd
check_io = chk\wder4, chk\zz9ycd
div_write = chk\lo98j3
year_on = chk\3w345f

[/]
@met = rw
@div = rw
@app_only= r
@check_io = r
@div_write = rw
@year_on = r

[/wedmin]
@check_io = rw
div_write= rw

[/doc/prod]
@div = rw
@app_only = r
year_on = rw
*******************************************************************************************
Record: C:/my_files/456_Milo_123-values.txt

#RakeBoss-Jan 21st Prod
[groups]
met = chk\rel_io_chk, chk\dev_op_io
div = chk\kzhr2x, chk\zz52t0, chk\czzjrt, chk\pzjwr3
jee_only = chk\zz9ycd, chk\hz659l, chk\zzktgj, 
check_io = chk\8u7y01, chk\zz9ycd
unique_key = chk\zz9ycd
year_on = chk\dytg6
[/]
@met = rw
@div = rw

[/Release]
@check_io = rw
@unique_key = rw

[/Redmine/Treehub]
@div = r
@jee_only = rw
******************************************************************************************
Record: C:/my_files/Docker_red-values.txt

#RakeBoss-Check it io.
[groups]
met = chk\rel_io_chk, chk\dev_op_io, chk\njk987
div = chk\gzlqvg, chk\zzkgyp, chk\lzg0rp, chk\gzp2kv
rakeonly = chk\qzvjq0, chk\kz6w6t, chk\bzy4kj, chk\dzfbhp

[/]
@met = rw
@div = rw
@rakeonly = r
******************************************************************************************
```

I'm trying to read the input file and write the formatted output to an Excel file. Every module or a set is separated by series of '*'. For the 1st set as seen below output should be in the below format

**1st set**

```
Record: C:/my_files/00_Roll_Tom-values.txt

#RakeBoss-Random as on 12/19/2016
[groups]
met = chk\rel_io_chk, chk\dev_op_io,
div = chk\kzhr2x, chk\zz52t0, chk\czzjrt
rakeonly = chk\rzgnsd, chk\cztw5h

[/]
@met = rw
@div = rw
@rakeonly = r
```

Output in excel should be

```
file_name   cluster       id                   case     access_levels

00_Roll_Tom   met        chk\rel_io_chk          /       rw
00_Roll_Tom   met        chk\dev_op_io           /       rw
00_Roll_Tom   div        chk\kzhr2x              /       rw
00_Roll_Tom   div        chk\zz52t0              /       rw
00_Roll_Tom   div        chk\czzjrt              /       rw
00_Roll_Tom   rakeonly   chk\rzgnsd              /       r  
00_Roll_Tom   rakeonly   chk\cztw5h              /       r
```

**For the 2nd set**

```
Record: C:/my_files/Rander-values.txt

#RakeBoss-Jan 21st QA
[groups]
met = chk\rel_io_chk, chk\dev_op_io
div = chk\541kmj, chk\zz52t0
check_io = chk\wder4, chk\zz9ycd
div_write = chk\lo98j3

[/]
@met = rw
@div = rw
@check_io = r
@div_write = r

[/wedmin]
@check_io = rw
div_write= rw

[/doc/prod]
@div = r
```

Output should be in the same format as the 1st set and so on for the remaining sets.

`Rander-values   met       chk\rel_io_chk   /            r
Rander-values   met       chk\dev_op_io    /            r
Rander-values   div       chk\541kmj       /            r
Rander-values   div       chk\zz52t0       /            r
Rander-values   check_io  chk\wder4        /            r
Rander-values   check_io  chk\zz9ycd       /            r
Rander-values   div_write lo98j3           /            r
Rander-values   check_io  chk\wder4        /wedmin      rw
Rander-values   check_io  chk\zz9ycd       /wedmin      rw
Rander-values   div_write lo98j3           /wedmin      rw
Rander-values   div       chk\541kmj       /doc/prod    r
Rander-values   div       chk\zz52t0       /doc/prod    r`

In the input file, i have mentioned only 4 sets, real time input file may have 1000 + sets (i.e. entries separated by series of *s)

I have searched over blogs and forum and decided to parse the input file as ini file and came up with the below code, unfortunately ini gem is no longer actively maintained with the latest Ruby versions. Any suggestion how to get it done apart from using the ini parsing options.

I'm new to programming and to Ruby , so pls. excuse. Thanks.

What I've tried:

```
require 'csv'
require 'inifile'

def modify(data)
  groups = data.delete('groups').map do |k,v|
    values = v.split(',').map(&:strip).map do |v|
      v.gsub(/[\n\r\0\t]/) do |char|
        case char
        when "\0" then '\0'
        when "\n" then '\n'
        when "\r" then '\r'
        when "\t" then '\t'
        end
      end
    end

    [k, values]
  end.to_h

  data.flat_map do |endpoint, attrs|
    attrs.flat_map do |cluster, access_level|
      c = cluster.gsub('@', '')
      groups[c].map do |id|
        {
          cluster: c,
          id: id,
          case: endpoint,
          access_level: access_level
        }
      end
    end
  end
end

records = File.read('input.txt').split(/(#.*\n|\*+\n)/).each_slice(4).flat_map do |r|
  data = Hash.new { |h,k| h[k] = Hash.new }
  IniFile::Parser.new(data, '=', ';#', 'global').parse r[2]

  file_name = r[0][/(?<=\/)[^\/]*(?=-values\.txt)/]

  modify(data).map { |d| { file_name: file_name }.merge(d) }
end

CSV.open('output.csv', 'wb') do |csv|
  csv << records.first.keys
  records.each do |hash|
    csv << hash.values
  end
end
```

Comment: @Gerry : Could you please help me here. Thank you.